# What is the shelf life for (unopened) Pino Grigio?

Tags: age

I recently came across a bottle of Pino Grigio that's a few years old (label says 2012, and that's probably when it was bought).  We usually only break out a bottle of wine for guests or a special occasion -- exactly the wrong time to find out that it's way past its use-by date.  We're usually more prompt in our consumption; this was an oversight.

I have the impression that whites are more fragile than reds in this regard, and that less-dry wines are more fragile than drier ones.  (Please correct any misunderstandings.)  How likely is it that I could serve this wine to people I like?  More generally, how long is too long?

The wine has been stored at room temperature in a room that isn't too hot (but isn't a cellar either), away from light.

Answer (score 3):

It’s tough to generalize, but most crisp whites have a best-before date of roughly two years from the vintage date on the label.

Answer (score 3):

Open and smell and you will know right away. If it smells OK then give it a taste.  If it has gone bad you will know.

A couple years as answered by Jamie.

In the fridge I have stored over two years and it was fine.  If you don't drink your white fast then best to store it in the fridge.  Even if you drink them fast then store in the fridge as they are best served chilled.

Whites (that I know of) don't get better with age so no reason age them.

If it has gone bad then you can use it as white wine vinegar.